# What happens to the past desires of a person when they get enlightened?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, maya, enlightenment, desire

Let's say a person who is a drug addict gets enlightened, then what will happen to his addiction? Will it just fade away just because he realized the drugs, the fun, and the one who enjoyed are part of maya and not real or at the level of maya the person will still need to struggle to get rid of his addiction just like anybody else other than the fact the person will know that it is not he who is struggling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bhagavad Gita 4.36  answers this question.

> अपि चेदसि पापेभ्य: सर्वेभ्य: **पापकृत्तम:** |
> सर्वं ज्ञानप्लवेनैव वृजिनं सन्तरिष्यसि
> Even if you be the **worst sinner among all sinners,** still you will cross over all the wickedness with the raft of *Knowledge* alone.
> Translation Swami Gambhirananda

Wisdom and Passion (for any vice or virtue as well) cannot co-exist. When the person acquires conviction over the Self , no longer can the person value / hold on to,  a passion/desire ,over any sense object whatsoever.. (Spiritual) wisdom does not occur on a impure mind..Once the Knowledge occurs , all struggle seizes , Sense of Peace would come about quickly without delay(jñānaṁ labdhvā parāṁ śhāntim achireṇādhigachchhati4.39)
The person isn't impelled by a desire to act , yet the person may  face the experience of prarabdha karma with equanimity of mind.

> naiva tasya kritenartho  ..self-realized souls have nothing to gain or lose either in discharging or renouncing their duties. Nor do they need to depend on other living beings to fulfill their interests.(BG 3.18)

PS:

> Chandogya upanishad [6.14.2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english/d/doc239324.html).--- yaani pravr.ttaphalaani---
> Those actions which have started yielding results and by which the body of the man of knowledge was brought into existence ,get exhausted only by their results being actually experienced, just as an arrow that has gathered momentum after having been discharged stops only when the momentum is exhausted.(Sri Shankara commentary Translation SN Saastri)

But the Jnani experiences it with equanimity of mind

*An enlightened , may not possess any addiction for  worldly things(be it drug  addiction or any other)..akin to case of an adult losing a natural inclination for toddler play things , which the same adult cherished previously ,  as a toddler.*